# React - You need to enable JavaScript to run this app, which happens only in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, safari, chakra-ui

I have a React application running in `localhost:3000`, which run successfully in Chrome.

When I navigate `localhost:3000` in Safari, there's nothing shown in the screen
[image]
[image]

I have checked that I have already enabled Javascript in Safari Preference.

How can I fix this?

**Update 1**

Seems like a Chakra UI stuff...
[image]

Comment: find the cause of the unexpected token for a start - what you've highlighted is NOT an issue since that text is NOT showing in the page itself - that text will always be in the HTML

Comment: @Jaromanda X please check my update

Comment: ahh, you're using safari older than version 13.1 since nullish coalescing operator was only introduced to safari in version 13.1 (or 13.4 on mobile IoS) - what version safari are you running? does your build environment have configuration for minimum browser support?

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes! I'm now using 13.0.5. How can I configure for minimum browser support?

Comment: By reading the documentation for your build environment

Comment: @Jaromanda X but I'm using localhost

Comment: @Jaromanda X I do not understand what you mean by the documentation for your build environment. Can you specify what it is?

Comment: Or do you mean webpack?

Comment: I have no idea what your development environment is, so no, I can's specify what it is - having said that, I see that my advice may not help anyway